# Symfony 2: Validate/add fields in form that are not included in the entity

Tags: symfony

My problem is that I want to validate a form to signup a user (that includes a CAPTCHA and a "repeat password" fields) in Symfony.

I know how to validate forms and create them by using createForm($form, $entity).

My problem is that, for instance in this case, my $entity is User. And from my point of view I shouldn't add a captcha field nor "repeat password" attributes in my entity, that doesn't make sense for me, but the form is validated against fields in the entity.

So!, **how can I validate my form when I have fields that are not included in my validated entity?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a form class for your entity and then you can add whatever fields you want in the form, but leave them out of the entity.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: I thought I was doing it wrong, thanks. To be honest I don't like that way to make it but seems that there is nothing more elegant....GRRrrrr